# Cannot complete installation of Windows 2012 R2 server foundation on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I am trying to install VMW Windows 2012 R2 foundation on the Windows 2012 R2 host. After completing the installation it is asking for administrator account password but does not take the mouse input or keyboard input. I have inserted the integration disk `vmguest.iso` in the VM, but keep getting this error message

> Mouse not captured in Remote Session.

I cannot also shutdown the machine at this point. Any ideas how to solve this?

[image: Image of the issue]

Comment: ok I can access the keyboard and can login to the administrator account but still cannot get to the mouse or run the integration services

Comment: You can't use the mouse until the Integration Services are installed. Have you inserted the Integration Services Setup Disk from the Actions menu? If so, have you installed the Integration Services? If the Integration Services Setup Disk doesn't autoplay then navigate to it via File Explorer using the keyboard and launch it.

Comment: Yes, ran setup from the integration services disk but it says that the integration services are already installed. BTW: 2012 r2 comes with integration services already installed it seems!

Comment: Yes. W2K12R2 includes the Integration Services in the OS. I had thought that maybe for some reason they didn't get installed when the OS installed. Have you tried rebooting the VM?

Comment: Yes did a restart but still the same issue

Comment: It looks like the issue is with W2K12R2 Foundation Edition which is probably not bundled with all services. I later tried with W2K12R2 standard edition and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This version of Windows 2012 (Foundation) can't be used as a virtual machine.

> cannot host virtual machines or be used as a guest operating system in a virtual machine.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx

The link is for Windows 2012, however same should apply for R2.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dau-blog/archive/2012/02/28/mouse-not-captured-in-remote-desktop-session-when-virtual-pc-vhd-file-runs-in-hyper-v.aspx) will be helpful..

In short the steps are:

1. Uninstall the Virtual PC Tools… but how to reach the start button without a mouse and a Windows Key?
   -> ALT+HOME is your friend and emulates the Windows Key!
   -> Now just type “features” and press enter to open the list of installed programs
   -> once the Programs and Features Window has opened press TAB until the actual list view has focus
   -> Press ENTER on the Virtual PC Tools and choose to uninstall
2. Install Hyper-V Tools now
   -> In the Hyper-V Console Menu choose to insert the Integration Services Setup Disk
   -> Now Autorun asks you whether to run the setup… just go for it.
3. The last and most tricky part (I didn’t know the option at all) is to make the guest OS use the changed hardware
   -> Press ALT+HOME and navigate to “Run”
   -> type msconfig and open the boot page
   -> Enable “Detect HAL”
   -> Close the dialogs and restart the system to activate your changes and your mouse should be working right away!

Comment: Tried this before but did not find the virtual pc tools in the list of installed programs. Maybe because it is windows 2012 r2 guest.